# How to setup reverse dns (rDNS) to my unmanaged vps server

Tags: centos, docker, email-server, vps, docker-compose

Recently I've deployed a mail server on my VPS server using mailcow which is using docker/docker-compose. For sometimes sending mail was working fine. But recently all my mails are getting rejected. One of the reason it is showing from google that, I don't have any PTR record. I am not a server guy, so I don't have much knowledge. I searched online, finding I need to setup rDNS. I haven't setup my rDNS yet. Right now when I lookup my dns using this command `host mail.myclearmargin.com` it is showing my ip address `194.163.151.74`. But when i'm doing the opposite `host 194.163.151.74`, It is showing this `74.151.163.194.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer vmi616136.contaboserver.net`. How can i updated this? If anyone can give me some insight, It would be really helpful.

Note: My OS is centos 8

Comment: Usually you can set this in the controlpanel of your vps-provider: https://my.contabo.com/rdns

Comment: @Virsacer My server is unmanaged VPS, it do not have any cpanel.

Comment: Not on your vps but on the page of the company where you rented the server...

Comment: @Virsacer I talked to them long ago, there isn't any option like that.

Comment: If the IP you gave is really yours, then Contabo is your provider and they write in their blog https://contabo.com/blog/prevent-e-mails-marked-spam/ "You have to change your PTR like in the upper example, what can be done easily in the Customer Control Panel." (I put the link to the CCP in the first comment - have you tried?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set this up with the hosting provider.

You own the domain names, they own the IP addresses. You can set forward lookups, they have to configure reverse lookups.

However, it you are on a “shared” IP address what you are asking is impossible as it would affect all other customers.

Comment: This is dedicated IP. Okay, i will talk to my hosting provider.

Comment: Is it possible to override it from my server using Bind? My ISP don't have much knowledge about it. Seeing few post related to Bind. Tried it, but not working.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed no it is not. It is 100% the responsibility of the provider. They own the IP addresses and are the only ones who can set reverse PTR records for those IP addresses. Some providers allow the customer to configure PTR via a control panel. Others require a phone call or support request to do so.

Comment: After talking further with my ISP, they were manage to add rDNS. Thanks for your info.